# Using JavaScript do replace all occurrences of a few strings in HTML by the user input from a prompt

Tags: javascript, replace, queryselector

**Context:** I'm a newbie in JavaScript and I'm learning as I go with a little program I built for my job on customer service. It's a HTML file with some some quick generic messages which are used by many attendants, each representing a branch from our company. I want each attendant to be able to customize their name and their branch's name (which are represented by the strings "YourName" and "YourBranch"). I feel I'm so close to getting it and this is the last thing I need to do before being able to share with my peers, which are very much in need of this solution. So I decided to ask for help.

**What I'm trying to do and what I tried so far:** I created a button that opens a prompt where they can input their info. The intention is to use their input so that it gets replaced in the HTML text. And I somewhat managed to do it with lots of google fu, but the replace operation only happened in the first occurrence. I want it to happen in all occurrences. I tried a loop but failed. All examples I found for loops were about increments or strings, and I'm using a user input. So I decide to trying another way using two replace() and global regular expressions, which you can see in the last portion of my JS code.

Can someone enlighten me, please?

Below, a small portion of my HTML file and my whole Javascript file. Didn't consider CSS relevant.

```js
const buttonName = document.querySelector('#buttonEditName')

const nameAttendant = document.querySelector('#attendantName')
const nameBranch = document.querySelector('#branchName')

buttonName.onclick = () => {
  const name = prompt('What is your name?')
  const branch = prompt('What is your branch name?')

  nameAttendant.textContent = `${name}`
  nameBranch.textContent = `${branch}`

  const textAnswer = document.querySelector('.content')
  textAnswer.textContent = textAnswer.textContent.replace(/nameAttendant/g, name)
  textAnswer.textContent = textAnswer.textContent.replace(/nameBranch/g, branch)
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <h1 class="main-title">Quick Messages</h1>

  <div class="container">
    <button id="buttonEditName">Edit attendant and branch info</button>
  </div>

  <h3 id="welcome">Welcome</h3>
  <p>
    Good morning! My name is <span id="attendantName">YourName</span> and I represent <span id="branchName">YourBranch</span>. How can I help you?
  </p>

  <p>
    Good afternoon! My name is <span id="attendantName">YourName</span> and I represent <span id="branchName">YourBranch</span>. How can I help you?
  </p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- you have several tag with same id it's an invalid syntax you should use class instead id in this case
- like you have several tag with same selector you should use querySelectorAll method to select all of them and loop on each instance to replace innerText with correct value

```js
const buttonName = document.querySelector('#buttonEditName')

buttonName.onclick = () => {
  const name = prompt('What is your name?');
  const branch = prompt('What is your branch name?');

  const textAnswer = document.querySelector('.content');
  [...textAnswer.querySelectorAll('.attendantName')].forEach(oneNamePlace => oneNamePlace.innerText = name);
  [...textAnswer.querySelectorAll('.branchName')].forEach(oneBranchName => oneBranchName.innerText = branch);
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <h1 class="main-title">Quick Messages</h1>

  <div class="container">
    <button id="buttonEditName">Edit attendant and branch info</button>
  </div>

  <h3 id="welcome">Welcome</h3>
  <p>
    Good morning! My name is <span class="attendantName">YourName</span> and I represent <span class="branchName">YourBranch</span>. How can I help you?
  </p>

  <p>
    Good afternoon! My name is <span class="attendantName">YourName</span> and I represent <span class="branchName">YourBranch</span>. How can I help you?
  </p>
```